# how to plot one topic against another in ros

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have two topics publishing the std_msgs/Float32 message. Is there a way I can plot the data in one topic against the other?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/66760/how-to-plot-one-topic-against-another-in-ros/) by [robzz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3420/robzz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 328 on 2013-07-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check out [rqt_plot](http://ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingTopics#Using_rqt_plot).

This provides a scrolling plot of data from multiple topics on the same axis, as a function of time. If you needed topic1 vs topic2, I don't know of an easier solution than writing a quick python node that listens to both topics then plots the data after a specified time.

EDIT: I don't love it (would love another alternative!), but I use matplotlib. The documentation isn't easy to get started with, so I'd just look at the [example code and plots in the gallery](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html).

---

Originally posted by [lindzey](https://answers.ros.org/users/2444/lindzey/) with karma: 1780 on 2013-07-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [robzz](https://answers.ros.org/users/3420/robzz/) on 2013-07-09**:
I've checked out rqt_plot, and as far as I can tell, it can't plot one topic vs. another. What would you use to plot in python?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a way to do that (Called XY plots) in PlotJuggler:

https://facontidavide.github.io/PlotJuggler/visualization_howto/index.html#display-a-xy-curve

https://github.com/facontidavide/PlotJuggler

---

Originally posted by [Davide Faconti](https://answers.ros.org/users/578/davide-faconti/) with karma: 308 on 2018-01-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-01-30**:
Some more information about the package would make this answer more useful. That way people don't have to exit the site to find out what it does.